# Python - Iterate through last row and add value as a data label in plot

Tags: python, dataframe

> I'm trying to iterate through the values of the last row in my dataframe and then get the value to add as a data label to my plot. But the below doesn't work I get the error

```
type numpy.ndarray doesn't define __round__ method
```

> My code is as below. If I change the str part of the text function to str = y, then the graph gives an output of [y value] i don't want the brackets I want to output the float itself. My eventual output I want is 14.9% where currently y = [14.90882042]

```
 for y in df_plot[-1:].T.values:
            plt.text(df_plot.index[1],y,round(y,2))
            print(y.astype(float))
```

> My output when i print each value print a numpy array of 1x1 rather than the value itself.

```
[14.90882042]
[24.05641512]
[17.16719185]
[18.61666735]
[25.25090525]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you put a comma accidentaly there, and you don't need to pass the "y" variable inside the `round()` function as you're already using the dot to apply te function to your variable. So that part should be like this: `plt.text(df_plot.index[1], y.round(2))`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've updated to the below but the txt comes up with brackets around it on the graph?

for y in df_plot[-1:].T.values:
        txt =str(y.round(2))
        plt.text(df_plot.index[1],y.round(2),txt)

Sorry I don't know how to format to change the above to code